# Use PKRevealController with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add PKRevealController to my Swift Project but it doesn't work. I think this is the problem:

**Setup**

1. Instantiate.

   PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:front leftViewController:left];
2. Configure.

   revealController.delegate = self;
3. Apply.

   self.window.rootViewController = revealController;

([Source of the PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/blob/master/Documentation/USAGE.md))

I cannot translate this Objective C to Swift without getting an error. 
PKRevealController was added by CocoaPods.

Comment: What error are you getting? 
If you want to use Objective C code in Swift you have to include an import of that code in [your bridging header.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: With the new CocoaPods version you don't need to use a bridging header and I don't have one. But thats not the problem, cause I use 5 Obj. C CocaPod Files without and they work. The Error is: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;

Comment: Show your Swift code

Comment: I've deleted because it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know how to use PKRevealController without bridging header in swift?

Comment: Can't help you if you don't show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use PKRevealController in your swift class, you need to instantiate as follow;

```
let revealController: PKRevealController = PKRevealController(frontViewController: nil, leftViewController: nil)

revealController.delegate = self

self.window?.rootViewController = revealController
```

Also make sure that your delegate class conforms to the PKRevealing protocol;

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKRevealing
```